# Android problems - findViewById and Intent do not work in this Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have to get the following code to work for a school project. 
The WeekActivity is supposed to show a schedule later.

However, there are two little errors: 
For some reason "final TableRow table = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRowDays);" cannot be resolved in this class, but Android Studio won't give me any hints on what might be the problem.

The small Intent in the last method linking to the other Activity doesn't work, either. Android studio says that it can't resolve the constructor of Intent? :?

If any of you see something I don't, any help would be appreciated. I'm stuck here and under time pressure too. >_<;

```
public class WeekActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<DatensatzStundenplan> inhalte;
int anzahlTage = 5;
int anzahlStundenMax = 11;
StundenplanTabelle tabelle;
ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener scaleGestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_week);

    scaleGestureDetector = new OnScaleGestureListenerWeek();
 //techotopia SimpleOnScaleGestureListener


    final TableRow table = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRowDays);

    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.day1);
    tv.setText("Mo");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.day2);
    tv.setText("Di");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.day3);
    tv.setText("Mi");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.day4);
    tv.setText("Do");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.day5);
    tv.setText("Fr");

    tabelle = new StundenplanTabelle();
    System.out.println(tabelle.getRows());
    inhalte = tabelle.getRows();


    faecherEintragen(this);
}

private void faecherEintragen(Context context) {
    final ListView weekTable = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weekTable);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    for(int i = 0; i<anzahlStundenMax; i++){
        View tr = li.inflate(R.layout.table_row_subjects, null, false);

        TextView tv;
        tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell_1);
        tv.setText(inhalte.get(i).getFachMo());

        tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell_2);
        tv.setText(inhalte.get(i).getFachDi());

        tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell_3);
        tv.setText(inhalte.get(i).getFachMi());

        tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell_4);
        tv.setText(inhalte.get(i).getFachDo());

        tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.cell_5);
        tv.setText(inhalte.get(i).getFachFr());

        weekTable.addView(tr);
    }
}

private void buttonPressed(){
    Intent i;
    i = new Intent(this, DayActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

This is the xml file activity_week:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableDays"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowDays"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day1"
            android:textColor="#29088A"
            android:text="MO"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
            android:width="80dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day2"
            android:textColor="#29088A"
            android:text="DI"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
            android:width="80dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day3"
            android:textColor="#29088A"
            android:text="MI"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
            android:width="80dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day4"
            android:textColor="#29088A"
            android:text="DO"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
            android:width="80dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day5"
            android:textColor="#29088A"
            android:text="FR"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:width="80dp"
            />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

   <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/weekTable"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tableDays"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

        <!--        <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/weekTable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </TableLayout>-->

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

...and this is table_row_subjects.xml, in case that should be relevant:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:id="@+id/tableRowSubjects"
       >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_1"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:text="TEST"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_2"
        android:width="80dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_3"
        android:width="80dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_4"
        android:width="80dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_5"
        android:width="80dp"
        />

   </TableRow>
```

...and the manifest, as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.dbg.aylin.stundenplan" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".WeekActivity"
            android:label="WeekActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DayActivity"
            android:label="DayActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try checking your recently-edited xml files for errors. Can you post your activity_week.xml file, too.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of you XML file `activity_week`?

Comment: where are tableRowDays id in your xml layout ? and day1, day2 and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry, posted the same thing twice. The real activity_week is up now. All mentioned TextViews of the code are declared there and Android Studio hasn't complained so far :?

Comment: At school, really?!  I had not Android even in university program! LOL

Comment: I haven't tested this but try `ScrollView t = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svname)`then `final TableRow table = (TableRow) t.findViewById(R.id.tableRowDays);` Adding the references gives the activity a grab. That might just be for fragments though.

Comment: Nevermind, try to replace scrollview with relative layout in my comment above.

Comment: The result was the same unfortunately. :/ my app keeps crashing.

Comment: Can you post the updated code? I would expect the suggestion from Script Kitty to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare TextView tv right under public class WeekActivity.
Your DayActivity class in Manifest file need to look like this:

```
<activity
android:name=".DayActivity"
android:label="DayActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="de.dbg.aylin.stundenplan.dayactivity" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

And then you can cal Intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("de.dbg.aylin.stundenplan.dayactivity");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference, unfortunately. Right now the biggest problem is the particular line with the TableRow :( It doesn't give me any errors with any of the other findViewById()-usages.

Comment: Post your Manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
change your code to this..

final TableRow table = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRowSubjects);

    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.cell_1);
    tv.setText("Mo");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.cell_2);
    tv.setText("Di");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.cell_3);
    tv.setText("Mi");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.cell_4);
    tv.setText("Do");

    tv = (TextView) table.findViewById(R.id.cell_5);
    tv.setText("Fr");
```